# Xamarin Extract Images from pdf file

Tags: image, pdf, xamarin, xamarin.android, itext

I have a pdf file in my server and i want a method to download the pdf file and extract images from that file. So far i have used XamiTextSharpLGPLv2, pdfbox but no luck so far.

```
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new Uri(url));
                for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                {
                    PdfDictionary pg = reader.GetPageN(i);

                    iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfObject PDFObj = reader.GetPdfObject(i);

                    if ((PDFObj != null) && PDFObj.IsStream())
                    {
                        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStream PDFStremObj = (iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStream)PDFObj;
                        try
                        {
                            //var pdfImage = new PdfImageObject((PRStream)PDFStremObj);
                            //var img = pdfImage.GetDrawingImage();
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {

                        }
                    }
                }
```

PdfImageObject is not found in XamiTextSharpLGPLv2, 
how can i use XamiTextSharpLGPLv2 to extract images or suggestions for any other library to achieve this would be a great help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is not a question

Comment: PDFBox does offer something from the command line: `ExtractImages`, see https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/commandline.html . I'm wondering why "no luck so far". Maybe it wasn't an image, but a vector graphic? I suggest you create a new question specifically with PDFBox and attach your PDF and describe what went wrong.

Comment: Can you post the PDF here? As @TilmanHausherr said, there may not even be any actual images, but vector. Or you could be looking at annotations? Seeing the file is an important next step.

Comment: Additionally, maybe you don't even need to do this. Why is extracting the images important for you? What will you do with them? Why not do this server side, why is doing this on the device important?

Comment: hi, pdf has only images (NO vector graphics), since i'm creating the pdf using XamiTextSharpLGPLv2 and upload it to the server, and when i get the response from server, i want to extract those same images from the pdf file.

Comment: I just see that it is on Android, so maybe what works in the 2.0 desktop version doesn't work there. Maybe the Android examples don't consider images in nested xobjects or patterns or inline images.

Answer (score 3):

> Xamarin Extract Images from pdf file

here are two libraries to extract images from pdf file

[XFINIUM.PDF](https://xfiniumpdf.blog/2016/05/20/extract-text-images-pdf-pages/)

[PDFTron](https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/samples/xamarin/cs/ImageExtractTest?platforms=xamarin)